# Google OAuth "The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID" error in Web Application

Tags: networking, amazon-ec2, https, oauth-2.0, reverse-proxy

I have a website hosted on an AWS EC2 instance with the following setup:

- Backend running on port 8000
- Frontend running on port 3000
- Both ports are not publicly open, but accessible within the internal
  private network.
- To access the application, I connect to this private VPN and access it via IP:port over HTTP (not secured with HTTPS).
- Google OAuth2 is used for login.

The issue I'm facing is that when accessing the application at http://101.10.10.10:3000/leaderboard and attempting to log in with Google, a pop-up window for Google authorization opens but remains blank, and in the browser console, I see the error: **"The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID."**

I've provided the OAuth properties within Google Cloud as an image for reference.

[image: Oauth properties]

**Questions:**

1. Could this issue be related to Google not being able to connect to the EC2 instance because all its service ports are accessible only within the private network?
2. Should I consider using a reverse proxy to reroute traffic to port 8000 instead of connecting directly to it?
3. Is this issue occurring because we are using HTTP instead of HTTPS for our application?

Any help in addressing these concerns would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!